# How do you use the Mesh To Hair add-on that you installed in Blender 4

Tags: mesh, add-on

I installed [Mesh to hair add on by Luwizart](https://youtu.be/mWAf9wpkmlQ) but I cannot find any controls for the add on.  I watched the video over and over hoping I could find out how to access it. Nothing. I am new to Blender. Can someone please direct me how to use this add on?

Comment: This add on was designed in 3.0 and the author may not have updated compatibility.  It does work in Blender 3.5, once you have gone to the geometry nodes workspace, clicked on new, and scrolled down the list of available nodes.

Comment: Hi, next time please add a link to the add-on so that everyone knows what you are talking about.